# What does wp-embed.min.js do in WordPress 4.4?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, embed, footer

**Question**

1. What does the `wp-embed.min.js` file do? I noticed it is added to the end of my blog page footer.
2. How can I get rid of it?

**Effort**

After some googling and I found [Embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) on the Codex. Why does WordPress think I want to add videos, etc. to my page by default?

**Environment**

WordPress 4.4

Comment: This is probabli related to wp as oEmbed server and not a client

Comment: I tried to add the answer to the first part of the question

Comment: Pretty sure it's just there to slow down your page.

Comment: @MarkKaplun is correct. wp-embed.min.js allows you to embed posts from remote WordPress sites into your own WordPress site, via oEmbed.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### What is it?

It is responsible for converting links into embed frames.

For example you can paste a Youtube video link into the editor content section and the Youtube embed will be generated for you when your page is viewed.

More information on [WordPress Documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/)

### How to get rid of it?

I could finally get rid of that using this:

```
function my_deregister_scripts(){
  wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_deregister_scripts' );
```

Comment: Adding it on action "wp_enqueue_scripts", also seems to work.

Comment: Yes, I'd use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and `wp_dequeue_script()` instead of `wp_deregister_script()`

Comment: @swissspidy `wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-embed' );` will not work - can you please run a test? The hood recommendation is valid.

Comment: Under WordPress 4.6 @Trix script works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Using this wont pass [themecheck](https://github.com/anhskohbo/wp-cli-themecheck).

Comment: Good article on Kinsta that uses filters to remove the script. https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-embeds-wordpress/

Comment: You didn't answer your question...

Answer (score 35):

I arrived at this thread with the same question: What does the wp-embed.min.js file do? None of the current answers accurately address this question.

Firstly, I am fairly certain that embed.min.js does not relate to embedding oEmbed content from other providers: Vimeo, YouTube etc. You can remove embed.min.js and those embeds will continue to function.

It relates specifically to embeding  *WordPress posts* from other people's blogs/websites. Embedding WordPress posts inside WordPress posts: so meta! [This feature was introduced in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/28/new-embeds-feature-in-wordpress-4-4/).

Disabling embed.min.js will stop that feature from working on your site.

You can test this easily: Paste the URL of someone else's WordPress post into one of your own posts. WP should convert that URL into an embedded widget. When you view your post on the front-end you will notice that your markup contains a blockquote and an iframe. The blockquote is a text-only link to the blog post you embedded, while the source of the iFrame is the blog post's URL with `/embed/` appended: its oEmbed endpoint.

embed.min.js hides the blockquote and reveals the iframe. It also does some other shenanigans to make the iframe play nice.

Now, try removing the embed.min.js script from your page using one of the methods described in the other answers. Reload your page and you'll notice that the blockquote is visible but the iframe is hidden.

In short: if you want to embed other people's WordPress posts into your own WordPress posts, leave embed.min.js alone. If you don't care about this feature then you can safely remove it.

Comment: Note that removing `embed.js` is not enough to properly disable embeds and might even lead to weird behavior if not done right. To completely disable these embeds, use the officially recommended [Disable Embeds](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-embeds/) plugin.

Comment: Working as expected and explained in word-press 5.x as well.

Comment: Incredible how wp adds useless bloat with every single version and official theme.

Comment: @swissspidywho recommends it? Seems abandoned.

Answer (score 9):

Trix's answer didn't work out for me on WordPress `4.4.1`, but I found a solution in the code of [Disable Embeds](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-embeds/) WordPress plugin. Add this code (modified) in your theme's `functions.php` file to remove the `wp-embed.min.js` file from the frontend completely:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    // Remove the REST API endpoint.
    remove_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_oembed_register_route');

    // Turn off oEmbed auto discovery.
    // Don't filter oEmbed results.
    remove_filter('oembed_dataparse', 'wp_filter_oembed_result', 10);

    // Remove oEmbed discovery links.
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links');

    // Remove oEmbed-specific JavaScript from the front-end and back-end.
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js');
}, PHP_INT_MAX - 1 );
```

Comment: Using `disable_embeds_init()` as the function name is a really bad idea. If you're going to install the Disable Embeds plugin one day, sky will fall down. I recommend you to just install the plugin, there's no benefit in adding this to your theme's functions.php file. If you insist on doing so, you should really use another function name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @swissspidy, I have updated the function's name

Comment: Note that this won't just remove the JS from the frontend/backend, it will also completely disable the ability to embed your posts on another site, WP Oembed will not work

Comment: Article on Kinsta elaborates on this method of using filters to remove it https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-embeds-wordpress/

Answer (score 4):

I think this part is still missing.

> What does the wp-embed.min.js file do? I noticed it is added to the end of my blog page footer.

The answer to this question is in the track. 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/35708

> **Embeds: Remove & characters from the inline embed JS.**
>
> Older versions of WordPress will convert those & characters to &, which makes for some non-functional JS. If folks are running an older release, let's not make their lives more difficult than it already is.

It will also try to sniff the user agent.

Comment: The text you have quoted ("Remove & characters from the inline embed JS" etc.). is a single commit message for the file, but does not describe the overall purpose of the script. I have provided my own answer which hopefully sheds more light.

Answer (score 1):

## Aug 2022 - WordPress 6.0.1

Others have given answers to OP's doubt.
I am just giving more insight into `wp-embed`

### What does the wp-embed.min.js file do?

In short, It will **make your link pretty**

> Add a block that displays content pulled from other sites, like Twitter or YouTube.
> *WordPress Block*

### Example

#### With `wp-embed`

[image]

#### Without `wp-embed`

If you turn off the `wp-embed` in the functions, this is how it looks in the front end.
[image]

### How can I get rid of it?

Something to know that this script sits in your footer

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://YOURSITE/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=6.0.1' id='wp-embed-js'></script>
```

So you have two options. One is using `wp_enqueue_scripts` and another is to use the `wp_footer`.

#### Using `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```php
function deregister_style_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_style_scripts', 100 );
```

#### Using `wp_footer`

```php
function deregister_style_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'deregister_style_scripts' );
```

### How to embed the link

Use the `Embed` block

[image]

### Embed doesn't work?

This usually happens when they do not want to embed their content within their site or outside. This can be controlled via `X-Frame-Options`, there are two directives `DENY` and `SAMEORIGIN`

#### Refused to connect

> x-frame-options: DENY

[image]

#### Sorry, this content could not be embedded.

> x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

[image]

### Read more

**About Embeds**: https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/
**x-Frame-Options**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options