# How to remove some external js files from source?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I need to remove some external .js files from source
here is source: view-source:buhehe.de/ausmalbilder/
There is 3 jquery library and I don't know what is difference, why is it not one enough?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://buhehe.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://buhehe.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/themes/tema/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Can I leave only one?

And how can I remove following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://buhehe.de/wp-content/themes/heatt/js/small-menu.js?ver=4.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://buhehe.de/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.1'></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use wp_dequeue_script to achieve this assuming they are using wp_enqueue_script to add the scripts in the first place.

Learn more about enquene and dequeue:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

```
function dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'http://buhehe.de/wp-content/themes/heatt/js/small-menu.js?ver=4.9.1' );
   wp_dequeue_script( 'http://buhehe.de/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.1' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Comment: this is not the good use of the functions `wp_dequeue_`... it's not the URL on the 1st argument but the handle identifier used to enqueue the file.

Comment: @mmm  This was just an example of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: Are you absolutely sure that you don't need them?

Secondly: I'm assuming `small-menu.js` is for the mobile menu and `wp-embed.min.js` you want in case you use embeds.
If I'm right, then you might want to keep the former. Aside from that you likely will find a `wp_enqueue_script` line for the former in your theme's `functions.php`. For the latter take a look at »[What does wp-embed.min.js do in WordPress 4.4?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/211701/22534)«.
To keep it short and simple about the jQuery lines, WordPress loads `jquery.js` and `jquery-migrate.min.js` for compatibility reasons. I would suggest you keep it that way, unless you are really sure what you're doing.
Additionally your theme loads another jQuery source, which generally isn't recommended. But there might be a reason to do so, so it can't be easily answered, if you simply can remove it. You'll likely find this one it the `functions.php` as a `wp_enqueue_script` line too.

Comment: I want to combine that small-menu.js, wp-embed.min.js in another html5.js.  is it possible? Also better would be one main .js joined, combined and not 3 different .js . is it possible in my case?

Comment: and about jqueyr,also would it be good if i remove all that .js s and load only one recent jquery library? for what does wordpress loads automatically  migrate.min.js and jquery.js? Can it not be loaded only one jquery? main, recent, updated version?

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე Sure, it is possible. It is advised to use the JQuery version bundled with WP. All the information you're asking for is out there and has been answered, perform a research on here and on the net. This [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283828/wp-register-script-multiple-identifiers) might interest you.